# How to delete the item in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

i have created an application in which i have two `ListView` with id listview and listview1, i tried to delete the item on long click..but getting number format excetion on long click..how to use longclink and delete the item on which i am clicking.and that item also delete from database too..,i m dislpaying name in the list,when user longclick on item it get delete.
Campaign.java

```
package com.example.smscampaign;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Campaign_Details extends Activity
         {
    Cursor c;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String str, str1, str2, str3, str4, str5;
    private Demo adapter;
    private Demo1 adapter1;
    static ListView listview, listview1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_demostration);
        TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ClosedCamapign);
        PackageInfo pInfo = null;
        try {
            pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        txt1.setText(pInfo.versionName);

        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textnum1);
        TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textnum2);

        final DatabaseHelp info = new DatabaseHelp(this);
        info.open();
        ArrayList<String> arr1 = info.getData1();
        final ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++) {
            list1.add(arr1.get(i));
        }
        int t1 = arr1.size();
        txt.setText(Integer.toString(t1));

        adapter1 = new Demo1(this, list1);
        // adapter1.setNotifyOnChange(true);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter1);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                String value1 = tv2.getText().toString();
                c = info.fetchChildren1(value1);
                if (c.moveToFirst())
                    str3 = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
                str4 = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("message")));
                str5 = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Contacts")));
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), str5, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                c.close();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Campaign_Details.this, SmsSend.class);
                intent.putExtra("key3", str3);
                intent.putExtra("key4", str4);
                intent.putExtra("key5", str5);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

        ArrayList<String> arr = info.getData();

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            list.add(arr.get(i));
        }
        int t = arr.size();
        txt2.setText(Integer.toString(t));
        adapter = new Demo(this, list);
        // adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

        listview1.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                String value = tv.getText().toString();
                c = info.fetchChildren(value);
                if (c.moveToFirst())
                    str = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("person_name")));

                str1 = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("scale_person")));

                str2 = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Contacts_person")));

                c.close();
                Intent Sendintent = new Intent(Campaign_Details.this, SmsSend.class);
                Sendintent.putExtra("key", str);
                Sendintent.putExtra("key1", str1);
                Sendintent.putExtra("key2", str2);
                startActivity(Sendintent);

            }

        });
        listview1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                String value = tv.getText().toString();
                long ltt= Long.parseLong(value);

                info.open();
                info.deleteEntry(ltt);

                info.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nextPage:
            Intent i = new Intent(Campaign_Details.this, SmsSend.class);
            SmsSend.conct.delete(0, SmsSend.conct.length());
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }



}
```

DataBaseHelp.java

```
  package com.example.smscampaign;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.w3c.dom.Comment;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    public class DatabaseHelp {

        public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_NAME = "person_name";
        public static final String KEY_SCALE = "scale_person";
        public static final String KEY_CONTACTS = "Contacts_person";
        public static final String KEY_To_ROWID = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_To_NAME = "name";
        public static final String KEY_To_SCALE = "message";
        public static final String KEY_To_CONTACTS = "Contacts";

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Himani";
        static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable";
        private static final String TABLE_ADD_MESSAGE = "Add_Message";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

        private DbHelper ourHepler;
        private final Context ourContext;
        SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

        public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            public DbHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  " + KEY_NAME
                        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SCALE + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"
                        + KEY_CONTACTS + ")");
                String CREATE_ADD_MESSAGE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ADD_MESSAGE
                        + "(" + KEY_To_ROWID
                        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  " + KEY_To_NAME
                        + " TEXT , " + KEY_To_SCALE + " TEXT  ," + KEY_To_CONTACTS
                        + ")";
                db.execSQL(CREATE_ADD_MESSAGE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS peopleTable");

                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Add_Message");
                onCreate(db);
            }

        }

        public DatabaseHelp(Context c) {
            ourContext = c;
        }

        public DatabaseHelp open() throws SQLException {
            ourHepler = new DbHelper(ourContext);
            ourDatabase = ourHepler.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        public void close() {
            ourHepler.close();
        }

        public long entryCreate(String name, String scale, String contacts) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            cv.put(KEY_SCALE, scale);
            cv.put(KEY_CONTACTS, contacts);
            return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        }

        public long entryCreate1(String name, String scale, String contacts) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_To_NAME, name);
            cv.put(KEY_To_SCALE, scale);
            cv.put(KEY_To_CONTACTS, contacts);
            return ourDatabase.insert(TABLE_ADD_MESSAGE, null, cv);

        }

        public ArrayList<String> getData() {

            String[] col = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCALE,
                    KEY_CONTACTS };
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col, null, null, null,
                    null, null);
            String run = "";
            int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
            int iScale = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCALE);
            int iMessage = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTACTS);
            ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                newList.add(c.getString(iName));
            }

            return newList;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getData1() {

            String[] col = new String[] { KEY_To_ROWID, KEY_To_NAME, KEY_To_SCALE,
                    KEY_To_CONTACTS };
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_ADD_MESSAGE, col, null, null, null,
                    null, null);
            String run = "";
            int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_To_ROWID);
            int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_To_NAME);
            int iScale = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_To_SCALE);
            int iMessage = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_To_CONTACTS);
            ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                newList.add(c.getString(iName));
            }

            return newList;
        }

        public Cursor fetchChildren(String KEY_) {
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE
                    + " WHERE person_name = ?", new String[] { KEY_ });
            return c;
        }

        public Cursor fetchChildren1(String KEY_) {
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ADD_MESSAGE
                    + " WHERE name = ?", new String[] { KEY_ });
            return c;
        }

        public String getScale(long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] col = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCALE,
                    KEY_CONTACTS };
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col, KEY_ROWID + "-" + l,
                    null, null, null, null);

            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                String scale = c.getString(2);
                return scale;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public String getScale1(long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] col = new String[] { KEY_To_ROWID, KEY_To_NAME, KEY_To_SCALE,
                    KEY_To_CONTACTS };
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_ADD_MESSAGE, col, KEY_To_ROWID + "-"
                    + l, null, null, null, null);

            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                String scale = c.getString(2);
                return scale;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public String getName(long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] col = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCALE,
                    KEY_CONTACTS };
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col, KEY_ROWID + "-" + l,
                    null, null, null, null);

            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                String name = c.getString(1);
                return name;

            }
            return null;
        }

        public String getName1(long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] col = new String[] { KEY_To_ROWID, KEY_To_NAME, KEY_SCALE,
                    KEY_To_CONTACTS };
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_ADD_MESSAGE, col, KEY_To_ROWID + "-"
                    + l, null, null, null, null);

            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                String name = c.getString(1);
                return name;

            }
            return null;
        }

        public String getContacts(long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] col = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCALE,
                    KEY_CONTACTS };
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col, KEY_ROWID + "-" + l,
                    null, null, null, null);

            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                String contacts = c.getString(3);
                return contacts;

            }
            return null;
        }

        public String getContacts1(long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] col = new String[] { KEY_To_ROWID, KEY_To_NAME, KEY_To_SCALE,
                    KEY_To_CONTACTS };
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_ADD_MESSAGE, col, KEY_To_ROWID + "-"
                    + l, null, null, null, null);

            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                String contacts = c.getString(3);
                return contacts;

            }
            return null;
        }

        public void updateEntry(long lt, String mName, String mScale,
                String mContatcs) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
            cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, mName);
            cvUpdate.put(KEY_SCALE, mScale);
            cvUpdate.put(KEY_CONTACTS, mContatcs);
            ourDatabase
                    .update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID + "-" + lt, null);
        }

        public void updateEntry1(long lt, String mName, String mScale,
                String mContatcs) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
            cvUpdate.put(KEY_To_NAME, mName);
            cvUpdate.put(KEY_To_SCALE, mScale);
            cvUpdate.put(KEY_To_CONTACTS, mContatcs);
            ourDatabase.update(TABLE_ADD_MESSAGE, cvUpdate,
                    KEY_To_ROWID + "-" + lt, null);
        }

        public void deleteEntry1(String ltt) throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ourDatabase.delete(TABLE_ADD_MESSAGE, KEY_To_ROWID + "=" + ltt, null);

        }

        public void deleteEntry(String value) throws SQLException {  //this is function that is used in lonclick
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=" + value, null);

        }
}
```

Comment: may be `tv.getText().toString();` is returning a non-valid integer. like `236482a` or `dq23648hjd` something like that...

Comment: why do u have a string value though ?? i mean its always good to have the id also because they can be unique. And why convert a string to long? If its really needed that way , may be you should change the way the delete query works.

Comment: @ Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille but m displaying the names from database in listview when i click on that name,i want related data get delete from database

Comment: check the ans if doubts ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are displaying data from the db itself, create a class like say :

```
1. class Data {
     int id; String name;
}

2. Modify the method `getData()` or `getData1()` whichever it is, in order to return 
a set of objects of type Data, that would contain the id, and corresponding name.

3. Create a custom adapter, that displays only the names

4. In the onLongItemClick listener get the value of the id clicked on like:
Data dObj = list1.get(position);
int id = dObj.getId();

5. Pass the id to the db method that performs the delete

6. The delete query should be one that compares the id , and you are done.
```